# How to populate a ListBox with external API response?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, listbox, httpwebrequest

I am making a request to an API, the only option I get is async get response

```
var r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
r.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponseMethod), state);
```

So, I built everything I need to get the data, and it is working. But the data is received in a different thread. My ListBox is bound to `StreamItems` that exists in my `MainViewModel`.

```
public ObservableCollection<StreamItemViewModel> StreamItems { get; private set; }
```

But I am in a different thread, so I cannot directly access this property to add new values to it. When I try:

```
StreamItems.Add(new StreamItemViewModel
{
    Content = responseContent
});
```

I get:

```
UnauthorizedAccessException - Invalid cross-thread access.
```

How can I add values that I got from the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do this on the UI thread - for that you can use [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190259%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
  StreamItems.Add(new StreamItemViewModel
  {
      Content = responseContent
  });
});
```